# Creating an array from JSON

Tags: c#, android, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to parse into an application a JSON string that is multidimensional. Here's a snipping of the string:

{"one": {"Title": "There Goes the Musical Neighborhood", "Body": "On April 18th Public Enemy..."},"two": {"Title": "Public Enemys DJ Lord Tours Australia", "Body": "Public Enemys...

So as you can hopefully see I have a key ("one") with a value set to a second JSON string with keys starting at "title" and "body" each with their own string values.

My webservice that i use to output the string works fine parsing in a SINGLE key-value pair
(EX. {"Title": "There Goes the Musical Neighborhood", "Body": "On April 18th Public Enemy..."} will parse and store the strings into my created class since I am using Json.Net and able to simple pair the keys with the class members.

Now I need to parse up to (but not necessarily all) five strings into my application to output to the user.

I first tried to Parse each value from the first array (EX. {"one": {"Title": ...) so that the string it stores would be a single JSON string that I can parse into its own object, but it seems to be returning an error with an unexpected token of "one" when I run my code.

Here is how I am parsing this.

```
        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format(@"http://moon.eastlink.com/~jandrews/webservice2.php"));

        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        request.Method = "GET";



        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)

        {

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)

                Console.Out.WriteLine("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))

            {

                var content = reader.ReadToEnd();

                if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content)) {

                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Response contained empty body...");

                }

                else {

                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Response Body: \r\n {0}", content);



                    NewsArray news = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewsArray>(content);
```

My response before deserializing the object is the entire string fine and outputs to the console in one piece, so I know the stream reader is grabbing the string. However once it tries to deserialize the object I get an error "Invalid token at line 1 position 9". It may have to do with how I am escaping the string brackets but it worked fine in the online parser. The site is where my full string is so you can take a look. Any idea what's wrong or if there is a better way of going about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works, but I think there is something wrong with the Json that site returns (See how i get the title )

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    string json = wc.DownloadString("http://moon.eastlink.com/~jandrews/webservice2.php");
    var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

    var items = jObj.Children()
                .Cast<JProperty>()
                .Select(c => new
                {
                    Title = (string)c.Value["{\"Title"],
                    Body = (string)c.Value["Body"],
                    Caption = (string)c.Value["Caption"],
                    Datestamp = (string)c.Value["Datestamp"],
                })
                .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Yes as I tried to point out I added the second bracket and escape to try and parse a "String" that would be formatted like a Json string that I could parse separately.
Is the code you wrote here using the System.Json or Json.Net reference?

Comment: I removed the strange things at the beginning of the string and changed my "one" key back into a number as it should be in an array.

Its strange but I am now getting an error that there is no type or namespace for JProperty and Children cannot be found in the current context.

Super sorry complete n00b here >.< if it helps I am working in Xamarin which uses Visual Studio and codes in C#

Comment: figured it out. I was using the wrong reference (Newtonsoft.Json instead of Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

thank you it's working beautifully now

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the version of .NET you are using you could just use something like this

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
public static T JsonDeserializer<T>(string jsonString)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));

        T obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
        return obj;
    }
```

Then use that function passing in whatever your type is as the generic type

Comment: The question is not about how can I generally deserilaize a json string, but how can I serialize/parse *that* json string given in the link. How would your class look like(the `T`)? BTW, OP uses Json.Net not `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

Comment: OP states "However once it tries to deserialize the object I get an error "Invalid token at line 1 position 9"." So yes he is trying to deserialize a string. Parsing = Deserializing = Breaking it down into an object. Using simple C# generics you could use that class as such

var parsedObj = JsonDeserializer<NewsArray>(originalJsonString);

Also the DataContractJsonSerializer is a built in class that I believe started in .NET 4.

Comment: triad_Mike, No need for lots of words, just post a class which can be used to deserialize that json string (+using your method) then I undo my downvote + upvote

Comment: I'll use your example:

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    string json = wc.DownloadString("http://moon.eastlink.com/~jandrews/webservice2.php");
    var jObj = JsonDeserializer<NewsArray>(json);
}

Comment: triad_Mike, I am still waiting. When will you post `NewsArray` which can work with your code?

Comment: OP here, I am SUPER sorry but I totally forgot to mention that my class NewsArray is a collection of 5 JsonObjects that were orignally set to string values
(like I said, i was trying to parse the code twice into separate objects but that was only since I am not the most advanced coder out there and that was what popped into my brain as a solution.